# Convert SVG infile to JPG outfile using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, phantomjs

I have set up the PhantomJS on Windows 7 and I am able to correctly run the following code from the command prompt:

`{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]};","constr":"Chart"}`

Now what I want to do is generate a JPG file from the SVG file.

But the below code does not work
`{"infile":"C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/Test.svg","outfile":"C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/phantomTest.jpg","constr":"Chart"}`

Content in SVG File is copied from http://export.highcharts.com/

I am getting

[image]

Comment: The phantomJS and highcharts-convert.js require to use JSON, not SVG element. Morever You cannot use references to local file system due to security reasons.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Thanks for the reply. But as mentioned on: http://export.highcharts.com/demo, a user can pass SVG content as param and generate the JPG file. I am trying to achieve the same thing. I am using local system just to get hands on with server export module.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince I tried with PhantomJS in command line as `phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile C:\Users\xxx\export.svg -outfile outChart.jpg` - renders fine. I also tried running PhantomJS as a server using `phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003` and from another console used `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data-binary "@C:/Users/xxx/options.js" 127.0.0.1:3003` and in the `options.js` file I have pasted SVG as `{"infile":"<?xml ` +(SVG file content here, with added \ before each double quotes)+`</svg>","outfile":"outXXA.jpg"}` - works fine too.